# Convert ISO vs Date in Java. With code example

Tags: java

I need to create a method received the date in two formats:

- 2022-05-27T17:38:00.000Z  (with time ISO)
- 2022-05-27 (basic date)

My code:

```
 private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";


 private String getFormattedDateTime(String date){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    Instant instant = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(date, Instant::from);
    return formatter.format(instant);
}
```

Throws exception on the simple date format:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-05-27' could not
> be parsed at index 10     at
> java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown
> Source)

My code currently works for the ISO. What is the best approach to check if the date is ISO or not?

Comment: What is your expected output date format ?

Comment: `if (date.length() == 10) { ... } else { ... }` ?

Comment: @leoOrion DATE_TIME_FORMAT

Comment: You expect the the input string to be in the format of `yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. That obviously doesn't match `2022-05-27`

Comment: You are expecting a time component in the output. For a basic date what do u want in the HH:mm ?

Comment: Use two different formatters, if one fails, try the other

Comment: @XtremeBaumer 00:00 in which time zone then?

Comment: For the usage: Both your formats conform to ISO 8601. Neither is what in ISO would be called "basic". Basic format is without the hyphens, like `20220527` or `20220527T173800Z`.

Answer (score 2):

A lazy way to do that will be by comparing the string length.

```
private String getFormattedDateTime(String date){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = null;
    if(date.lenght()>10)
       // initialize formatter for '2022-05-27T17:38:00.000Z'
    else 
       // initialize formatting for '2022-05-27'

    //rest of your code

}
```

You will be needing 2 formatters though for both ISO and Basic Date.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a single formatter, use multiple formatters.  The problem you have though, is one value is a date value (without time), so it's not possible to convert it to an `Instant` (I know, I tried ), instead, you need to be able to build some flexibility into the parsing workflow to inject a "default" time value and (as I also discovered) a time zone.

Something maybe like...

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
```

as an example.

Then you place all the formatters you want to try into a array or `List` and loop over them until either one works or you run out of formatters to try, for example...

```
public Instant convert(String value, DateTimeFormatter[] formatters) {
    for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatters) {
        try {
            return formatter.parse(value, Instant::from);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException exp) {
            // You should be able to ignore this
            // if you're not trying to debug reasons
            // why a particular value fail
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you really wanted to, you could collect all the exceptions and wrap them up into a unified `BatchDateTimeParseException` and throw that at the end instead, if you really wanted to collect the reasons why the formatters failed, up to you.

And then you could simply call it using something like...

```
DateTimeFormatter[] formatters = new DateTimeFormatter[]{
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME,
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0)
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"))
};
System.out.println(convert("2022-05-27T17:38:00.000Z", formatters));
System.out.println(convert("2022-05-27", formatters));
```

Which will output something like...

```
2022-05-27T17:38:00Z
2022-05-27T00:00:00Z
```

Be warned though, this is just a conceptual idea and I bet there are a tone of possible gotchas you might have to figure out by tweaking the formatters for different inputs, but you're providing different date and date/time values and asking for a single unified result.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go about this is to first try to describe exactly what format you are accepting: in your case, it's not an ISO_INSTANT, but a date part with an optional UTC time part. So create a formatter with exactly that format, and then use [parseBest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...)):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd['T'HH:mm:ss.SSSVV]");
    TemporalAccessor parsed = formatter.parseBest("2022-03-01", Instant::from, LocalDate::from);
    Instant instant = parsed instanceof LocalDate d? d.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) : (Instant) parsed;
    System.out.println(instant);
```

This will accept your input in either format.